# Print limited number of elements in collect_set array using printf function

Tags: hive, printf, hiveql

I want to `printf()` just the first 3 patients in `collect_set()` of patient numbers.

**A**.  I have created "patient_list" using collect_set

```
collect_set(distinct patient_seq) AS patient_list
```

which yields arrays of patients numbers of varying length (4, 5 or 6 digits)

Example:

```
["16189","26599","406622","419117","5551"]
["223587","224663","232072","326504","433430","436673","54540","58188","74118"]
```

**B**.  I then stripped out the commas and quotes and separated by '*' (in order to grab just the first 3 patients, in the next step):

```
concat_ws('*', patient_list) AS pat_list
```

This produces:

```
16189*26599*406622*419117*5551
223587*224663*232072*326504*433430*436673*54540*58188*74118
```

**C**.  I tried to use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to create a new variable (pat_list_short) containing just the first 3 patients, **but this function is not supported in hive 1.1.0** (not supported until 1.3.0).

```
substring_index(pat_list, '*', 3) AS pat_list_short
```

What other option do I have?

I want to feed the pat_list_short into the PRINTF using %s  in order to print out just the first three patient numbers for review team.  Since the patient num varies in length I can't just limit the print to a certain length

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the data you provided

```
--------------
key  |  pat_id
--------------
1       16189
1       26599
1       406622
1       419117
1       5551
2       223587
2       224663
2       232072
2       326504
2       433430
2       436673
2       54540
2       58188
2       74118
```

you can use this [UDF here](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/blob/master/src/main/java/brickhouse/udf/collect/TruncateArrayUDF.java) to truncate an array to a desired length.  There are instructions on the [main page](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse) how to build and use the jar.

**Query**:

```
add jar /path/to/jar/brickhouse-0.7.1.jar;
create temporary function trunc_array as 'brickhouse.udf.collect.TruncateArrayUDF';

select key
  , concat(' ', trunc_array(collect_set( pat_id ), 3)) pat_list_short
from db.tbl
group by key
```

**Output**:

```
----------------------
key  |  pat_list_short
----------------------
1       5551 26599 16189
2       232072 58188 223587
```

I must admit I'm a bit unclear has to how `printf()` plays a part in this problem as the query returns a result and prints it.  It is also with noting that in your query in **A**, the `distinct` in `collect_set(distinct)` is redundant, as `collect_set`'s purpose is to collect *distinct* elements.

Comment: Thanks GoBrewers.  The print() is used because we have a paragraph of text in which the pat_list_short is only one of many data points needing to be printed for client review.  I will try the trunc_array.  My work-around yesterday was to do the following:   SELECT Biz
, prov
, CONCAT_WS(' ', SORT_ARRAY(COLLECT_SET(patient_seq))) AS patseq_list 
FROM ( 
   SELECT DISTINCT Biz
, prov
, patient_seq
 , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Biz, prov ORDER BY patient_seq) AS pat_seq_order
  FROM pat_table
) a
WHERE pat_seq_order <= 3
GROUP BY Biz, prov;